# applications unable to use /tmp

Tags: mysql, php, tmp

The disk on a Ubuntu server filled up causing a website to fail and some database corruption. After freeing some space (rogue wordpress backup plugin) and reimporting the database we found some functions of the site where not working.

I fixed some of the problems by changing the PHP upload_tmp_dir do be something other than /tmp. I still had issues but then I changed the mysql tmpdir to be something other than /tmp

/tmp was owned by root, had 777 permissions and I was able to write to it at the command line.
I've not yet removed and recreated the directory as I want to understand the problem.

What could be causing the problems with applications writing to /tmp? How can I diagnose and get to the root of this issue?

Comment: Might be worth setting the shell for the `www-data` user to `/bin/bash` (with `chsh`), changing to the `www-data` user (with `su www-data`) and then seeing if you can write to the `/tmp` directory from there. That should make it a bit easier to debug. Importantly, though, don't forget to change the shell for `www-data` back to `/bin/false` afterwards.

Comment: that was a good idea although did not show anything. I was able to write to /tmp while I was the www-data user. i also tried mysql user.

Comment: What error messages are you getting then? Sounds a bit odd if the `www-data` user can write to it.

Comment: Nothing in error logs, just certain features not working in the site, which worked again after the change. I'm going to write some simple scripts to reproduce the issue as I appreciate Ive been a bit vague.

Comment: Yeah - to be honest, it doesn't seem as though writing to `/tmp` is your problem, at least as far as PHP is concerned. Maybe MySQL or Apache are trying to use `/tmp` for something, and need restarting?

Answer (score 0):

Is /tmp partitioned seperately on your system?  If so perhaps it remounted as read-only during your recent problems.

Ensure that the permissions are completely correct, you should have the sticky bit set on temp.
'chmod 1777 /tmp'

Comment: it's not separate, I can write to it. stickybit is set.

Answer (score 0):

Is the system running [AppArmor](http://wiki.apparmor.net/) or [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/)? If so, these may be denying access to specific applications (but shells are unrestricted). Check `/var/log/apparmor/` or `/var/log/audit/` for permission denied messages.